# Sass "For" and "Multiple Of"

Tags: css, sass

i have a list of box.

```
#box-1 {}
#box-2 {}
#box-3 {}
```

in sass i wrote:

```
@mixin boxnumerati($levels)
{
  @for $i from 1 to $levels
  {
    #box-#{$i}
    {
      @if $i == 2 {
        background: #ff0000;
        height: 200px;
        width:200px;
        display: inline-block;

      } @else {
        background: #000;
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want that every multiple of 2 the box is red.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modulo operator **%**:

```
@mixin boxnumerati($levels)
{
  @for $i from 1 to $levels
  {
    #box-#{$i}
    {
      @if $i%2 == 0 {
        background: #ff0000;
        height: 200px;
        width:200px;
        display: inline-block;

      } @else {
        background: #000;
        height: 100px;
        width:100px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
    }
  }
}
```